# Removing field that I concatenated to break my group by clause and show unique values

Tags: sql, group-by, concatenation, union

This is going to be an easy one for you.

I have used Union to join two table and, therefore I am using a group by clause.

I have to values that are exactly the same in every way other than the fact they need to display as separate lines.

this is my column:

`(select (concat(productiondetail.detailid, ProductionDetail.Description)) as [Description]`,

and that result gives me:

```
SM1250  | 11078Metabisulphite - 1250KG Bags | $ | 500.00

SM1250  | 11079Metabisulphite - 1250KG Bags | $ | 500.00
```

Now I want to remove the numbers in the Description.

Note: the Numbers are sequential and the Descriptions are of various lengths.

Comment: I have to concatenate to make them unique values but i only want to display the second value.

Comment: Post how your result should look like

Comment: SM1250 | Metabisulphite - 1250KG Bags | $ | 500.00

Comment: why dont we fix your union query instead of fixing this crap?

Comment: I'm creating a Template - the rest is fine and only when there is, uncommon duplicate description/item, is it grouping it otherwise it is working fine. Is there no way of removing the first 5 characters?

Comment: In a years time when they get to the point that the detailid is 6 characters I will make the change to remove 6 characters.

Comment: So you put the number there, because you want it there in all rows except for the duplicate rows? (Otherwise I wouldn't see any sense in it.)

Comment: Are you only adding the numbers because UNION only keeps one instance of the value? Can't you just use UNION ALL?